# Form validation not working with progressButton js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I've been working on this website with an animated submit button with a 3d built-in proggress bar:

http://add.digital/contato.php

For the submit button, I used this plugin:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/12/12/progress-button-styles/

Everything works beautifully, the loading bar runs smoothly and there are no problems with the form submission. The problem is the validation, which doesn't seem to work. The submit button ("Enviar") is a button tag. When I change it for an input tag, validation works, but the proggress bar doesnt, and vice-versa. I've tried reproducing the effect with an input tag, but it didn't work. So I tried to work on the form validation, which seemed more approachable. I've run quite a few solutions I found here on SO and on other websites regarding form validation with button tags, but I got pretty much the same result from all of them: when hitting the submit button, the error messages for empty fields are shown, but noe of them stops the progress bar animation and the form submission. I've also searched for queries related to Ladda.js, which is a similar plugin, but I can't find a way to validate the form and stop the animation and submission when necessary. I've checked the entire code (as a newbie), and tried many different solutions, but wasn't able to sort this matter, which is quite annoying. Any help or guidance on how to gou about with this would be much appreciated.

Below is the form:

```
   <form action="envia_mail_a2.php" method="POST">
      <div class="input-group">
         <label for="nome" class="hidden"></label>
         <input class="input-custom" type="text" placeholder="Nome"          name="edtNome" id="edtNome" required>
      </div>

      <div class="input-group">
         <label for="email" class="hidden"></label>
         <input class="input-custom" type="text" placeholder="E-mail"     id="edtEmail" name="edtEmail" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
         <label for="telefone" class="hidden"></label><input class="input-    custom" type="text" placeholder="Fone" id="edtTelefone" name="edtTelefone" required>
      </div>

      <div class="input-group">
         <label for="mensagem" class="hidden"></label>
         <textarea class="input-custom expanding" placeholder="Mensagem"       rows="1" name="edtMensagem" id="edtMensagem"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="input-group text-right">                
         <button type="submit" id="btnEnviar" name="btnEnviar" class="submit progress-button"  data-style="rotate-angle-bottom" data-perspective data-horizontal>Enviar</button>
      </div>
   </form>
```

And here the validation (original code, as it was when I took over the project, without my attempts):

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $("button#btnEnviar").click(function(e) {
                var nome = $("#edtNome").val();
                var mail = $("#edtEmail").val();
                var fone = $("#edtTelefone").val();
                var mensagem = $("#edtMensagem").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "envia_mail_a2.php",
                    //context: document.body,
                    //dataType: 'text',
                    data:       "nome="+nome+"&mail="+mail+"&fone="+fone+"&mensagem="+mensagem,

                    success: function(){
                        //alert('Enviado com sucesso')
                        setInterval(function(){ 
                                $("#edtNome").val('');
                                $("#edtEmail").val('');
                                $("#edtTelefone").val('');
                                $("#edtMensagem").val('');
                            }, 3000);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Erro ao enviar');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Once again, thanks for all the attention

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the code on the page, when calling `new ProgressButton`, there are two parameters passed to the constructor ... the button HTMLElement that will be turned into a progress button via the plugin, and a callback function that will determine what happens when the newly created progress button is clicked.  Right now you have two click handlers on the progress button.  One that is being passed into the `new ProgressButton()` call, and another one that you've pasted above that is created when the document is ready.  The one being passed into the `ProgressButton` constructor is handling the animation of the button, and the additional click handler you've pasted above is taking care of validation.  You need to move the validation code into the click handler that is being passed to the `ProgressButton` constructor so that the animation happens in-sync with validation.  For instance, you could trigger the animation as the result of a `success` return from the validation service, or you could do something else to the button if there is an error.  But all this should happen from a single handler since the validation is happening asynchronously, and right now, since the animation and validation are happening from two different handlers that are both triggered by clicks on the button, you're not able to sync those two processes up.

So I'm thinking something like this:

```
new ProgressButton( bttn, {
    callback : function( instance ) {

         var nome = $("#edtNome").val();
         var mail = $("#edtEmail").val();
         var fone = $("#edtTelefone").val();
         var mensagem = $("#edtMensagem").val();

         var animation = function() {
             var progress = 0,
             interval = setInterval( function() {
                 progress = Math.min( progress + Math.random() * 0.1, 1 );
                 instance._setProgress( progress );
                 if( progress === 1 ) {
                     instance._stop(1);
                     clearInterval( interval );
                 }
            }, 200 );
         }

         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "envia_mail_a2.php",
                //context: document.body,
                //dataType: 'text',
                data:"nome="+nome+"&mail="+mail+"&fone="+fone+"&mensagem="+mensagem,

                success: function(){
                    //alert('Enviado com sucesso')
                    //call the animation
                    animation();
                    },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Erro ao enviar');
                    //do another animation if there is an error
                }
             });
         });
    }
} );
```

To be honest, progress bars aren't great for AJAX calls when you're not able to really tell what the "progress" of the call is ... I guess you could do something that worked off the `readyState` of the XHR object using `onreadystatechange` events, but often times most AJAX progress indicators like this are some type of looping animation.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but it didn't work, bttn is not defined.

Comment: I'll try working with readyState as you suggested, should I be allowed more time on this project. :)

Comment: `bttn` should be the `<button>` element ... if it's not defined, then define it by assigning it the HTML `<button>` element like so: `var bttn = document.getElemementById("btnEnviar");`

Comment: By assigning the HTML element to define bttn, neither the form submission or the plugin work.

Comment: In looking at the code on the original page, the value of `bttn` should not be undefined ... is there a way to see what you're doing now?

Comment: I've tested so many different solutions and neither of them worked. At the moment the code on the page is the same as before my original post

Comment: Just saying, I'm confused why that variable is undefined ... and I'm not sure why the code above isn't working because of the undefined variable.  It would be nice to see what you have tried to better understand what "not working" means, and hopefully fix the issue.

Comment: I've tried solutions proposed on this post:http: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707743/html5-required-validation-not-working  to validate the button tag with html required attribute- it worked, the tooltip with the message would show up, but the form would still be submitted.

Comment: Also some of the solutions from this post- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914626/jquery-validation-with-button-type-rather-than-submit-type-for-a-form  and got pretty much the same result, validation works but doesn't stop thje form from being submitted either. I've also tried some similar solutions from other sources with the same result.

Comment: the progress bar plugin I'm using has an error display, which doesn't get triggered. Then I tried other ways to validate the form and stop the loading animation and the form submission when theere is an error, which I haven't been able to achieve.